# Why we can't employ classical wave equation in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Why the classical wave equation is not compatible with quantum wave function?
( Here I am talking about the wave function which we associate with some particle and by "classical wave equation" I mean that differential equation of mechanical waves that we study)

Comment: *Which* classical wave function? How do you think it should be "compatible", and what do you actually mean by that?

Comment: I was talking about the wave function which we associate with some particle and by "classical wave equation" I mean that differential equation of mechanical waves that we study

Comment: I think Diablo is talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation . It could come from the fact that some people use the word "wave" to describe solutions to that equation, while in the context of quantum mechanics, that isn't the case. Diablo seems to be wondering if the two equations can be somehow seen to be related (maybe in $|\psi|^2$ rather than $\psi$? idk. But I would be interested in the answer.

Comment: Yeah you got it right

Comment: Diablo do you want to edit that into your question to make it a bit more specific? Maybe then it will be reopened

Comment: Yeah doublefelix